# Initializing objects belonging to ManyToManyField from data in-memory

Tags: python, django

I'm working with instances of database models where I need to construct the object from data in-memory (using Python-style `o = Object()` as opposed to `ModelClass.objects.create()`. Whether or not the data will be saved in the database is to be decided later, when a call to `o.save()` would be used.

These models have a `ManyToManyField` and own a number of child objects. Problem is, I can't `add()` to the `ManyToManyField` until the child objects are actually saved. How can I construct these objects in such a way that `save()` can be called later? Every potential solution I've found to this problem does not actually do what I want.

Here's some example code showing what I'm trying to do:

```py
class Author:
  # ...
  @classmethod
  def create(cls, data):
    # ...
    pass

class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  pages = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

  @classmethod
  @transaction.atomic
  def create(cls, data):
    try:
      with transaction.atomic():
        b = cls(title=data["title"],
                pages=data["pages"])

        # This works, but has an unwanted side effect: authors are saved to the database
        # as they're created here while the Book is not saved.
        b.authors = Author.objects.bulk_create([Author.create(a) for a in data["authors"]])
        return b

    except Exception:
      # ...
      raise

################### Later on...
# This data is NOT static - it's formed from JSON which comes from an API. Just is here as an example.
data = {
  "title": 1,
  "pages": 934,
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "John Smith",
      # ...
    }
  ]
}

# We're going to use this now, but we're unsure if we want to actually save
# the object to the database.
b = Book.create(data)

# Save the data to the database if we want to.
b.save()
```

Comment: Are the authors already in the Database? or are you creating them like in an initial run?

Comment: Creating them like in an initial run. I don't want them in the database at all at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I can think off is queuing the operations and perform them when you call `save()`.

```
class PostponedOpMixin(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._postponed_ops = []
        super(PostponedOpMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _getattr(self, attr):
        result = self
        for part in attr.split('.'):
            result = getattr(result, part)
        return result

    def postpone(self, op, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:  # execute now if self already has a pk
            return self._getattr(op)(*args, **kwargs)             
        self._postponed_ops.append((op, *args, **kwargs))

    def save(self, *args, *kwargs):
        super(PostponedOpMixin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        while self._postponed_ops:
            op, args, kwargs = self._postponed_ops.pop(0):
                self._getattr(op)(*args, **kwargs)

    def Meta:
        abstract = True
```

This way you can do:

```
class Book(PostponedOpMixin):
    ...
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    ...

instance = Book()
instance.title = "Romeo and Juliet"
instance.postpone('authors.add', shakespeare)
...

# and some time later:
instance.save()
```

This code is untested and intended as a start point. Any bug is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I'll play around with this and accept the answer soon if there are no others, thanks! This *must* be a common idiom, I can't believe there's no real solution to it.

Comment: So I had a chance to look at this in detail, and it'll definitely work. I'm accepting your answer with my gratitude. I still just feel it's kind of a shame that there is no better solution available.

Comment: Also, I apologize the small bounty was all I had to offer!

Comment: You may want to keep it open for a few days, questions without an accepted answer tend to get more attention and someone may came up with a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could postpone the actual book's authors adding to the moment you are sure you want to save that book into the database.
In the meantime, you could store a list of processed (but not yet saved) author objects for each book object.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    pages = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

    @classmethod
    @transaction.atomic
    def create(cls, data):
        try:
            b = cls(title=data["title"],
                    pages=data["pages"])
            b.author_list = list()
            for a in data["authors"]:
                b.authors_list.append(Author.create(a))
            return b
        except Exception:
            # ...
            raise
```

Then, when you are sure you want to save the object, you have to save all the authors in that list, and then add them to the 'authors' field in the corresponding book object.